# Place imageview below imageview programmatically

Tags: android, parameters, position, imageview

I'm trying to place an imageview below another using layout parameters, but it is not working..
I want to accomplish this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/myFSu.jpg

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

                    iv_album[i] = new ImageView(main.this);
                    iv_album[i].setImageBitmap(resized_a_p);
                    iv_album[i].setPadding(0, 5, 5, 0);
                    iv_album[i].setId(i);
                    iv_album[i].setOnLongClickListener(main.this);
                    iv_album[i].setOnClickListener(main.this);
                    if (i>1){
                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, iv_album[i].getId() - 1);
                    }
```

what is wrong  ?

Comment: `iv_album[i].getId() - 1` won't give you the appropriate ID.  `iv_album[i - 1].getId()` *might* work on assumptions based off what little code you provided.

Comment: I had it that way before, it changes nothing..
My "i" variable starts at 1, so the ID is never 0.. I read somewhere this might gave errors.. makes no difference.

Comment: Looks to me like you're not applying the LayoutParams `params` to the ImageView anywhere. I'm sure you'll want to call `iv_album[i].setLayoutParams(...)` somewhere down the bottom.

Comment: I use this: layout.addView(iv_album[i], params);

Comment: I've been trying to solve this for a week.. Need help people ! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a LayoutParams for each ImageView works for me:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.layoutConnection);

ImageView[] iv_album = new ImageView[8];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    iv_album[i] = new ImageView(this);
    iv_album[i].setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    iv_album[i].setPadding(0, 5, 5, 0);
    iv_album[i].setId(i + 1); // BELOW id 0 doesn't work
    if (i > 0) {
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, iv_album[i - 1].getId());
    }

    layout.addView(iv_album[i], params);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I LOVE YOU ! just needed to create a new layoutparams for each imageview like you said !